# List only the output of 5 rows

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Long story short ive done 75% the story where I wanna list the business commissions and the final step is to only show 5 of the rows that are resulted.

LIMIT clause dont seem to work on one hand XD

```
   -- Top 5 Sales Commissions of 2018 in the Car Business - Employee of the year award 
   SELECT Emp_IDs, Emp_Name, Sale_Num, Sale_Date, Commission 
   FROM  Sales, Employee_Details, Sales_Comm
   WHERE Sales_Comm.EMP_id = Employee_Details.Emp_ID
   AND Sales_Comm.Sale_Num = Sales.Sale_No
   ORDER BY Commission DESC;
```

I would like to select the sales commissions table order the commissions high to low and then select 5 rows out of all the results.

Comment: Shows a syntax error about partial railroad rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Emp_IDs, Emp_Name, Sale_Num, Sale_Date, Commission
FROM
(
    SELECT Emp_IDs, Emp_Name, Sale_Num, Sale_Date, Commission,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Commission DESC) rn
    FROM Employee_Details ed
    INNER JOIN Sales_Comm sc
        ON ed.Emp_ID = sc.Sale_Num
    INNER JOIN Sales s
        ON sc.Sale_Num = s.Sale_No
)
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Note that I updated your query to use modern, explicit join syntax, which is the preferred way of writing SQL these days.

Although `FETCH FIRST` might run faster than the above, assuming your Oracle version supports it, the above code has one possible advantage.  If you ever decided to refactor the query and use a different metric, then you would only need a very minor change.  For example, if you wanted to retain the top 5 ranking commissions, then you would only need to swap `ROW_NUMBER` for `RANK` (or maybe `DENSE_RANK`).

Comment: A shame that I dont get to advanced syntax till next yr. I use the basic join: tablename.columnname = tablename.columnname

Comment: Tried with your version there Tim, the output produces no tables being selected. I hate being constraints of version 11g express Oracle

Comment: What does the inner query return when you run it?  How many records do you see?  If you see nothing, then maybe you are using the wrong join conditions.

Comment: I am using exactly what you've shown but could it be due to the version Im using otherwise the implementation would work at the end of the day

Comment: @PL8YR If you can setup an Oracle demo with data at [this demo site](https://dbfiddle.uk), I can have a look at it and see what is going on.  I suspect your data at this point.

Comment: Are you constrained? 18c xe is now available for Linux, so you're not stuck with 11 any more

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, there is no `LIMIT` clause. If you are on 12C or newer, you can use a [`FETCH`](http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-fetch/) clause to limit the number of results. See the last line of the modified query. It's idiotic and verbose but that's Oracle.

```
-- Top 5 Sales Commissions of 2018 in the Car Business - Employee of the year award 
SELECT Emp_IDs, Emp_Name, Sale_Num, Sale_Date, Commission 
FROM  Sales, Employee_Details, Sales_Comm
WHERE Sales_Comm.EMP_id = Employee_Details.Emp_ID
AND Sales_Comm.Sale_Num = Sales.Sale_No
ORDER BY Commission DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY; --this statement here
```

Comment: Oh, stunning, not versed at all in Oracle, but good to know though !

Comment: Ahh I am using 11g express edition to be more specific

Comment: If you're on version 11, then unfortunately `FETCH` is not supported. See the post by @TimBiegeleisen below.

Comment: Found the solution had to use WHERE rownum <=5... Now I gotta embed that with the ORDER BY commission DESC.